# How to use models app in another app in django?

Tags: python, django

I'am looking a solution in my case. I have a website witch contains the main app calling 'bajki'. I've create a 2nd app calls 'ustawienia'. In 'ustawienia' I want to changing the thinks in `<head>` and footer section like: title, meta description, name of footer(like standard settings in populars cms). So I've create a class in models.py in 'ustawienia' app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Ustawienia(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name="Tytuł strony(title)")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=280, verbose_name="Opis META(description)")
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nazwa LOGO")
    footer = models.TextField(verbose_name="Opis stopki")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ustawienia Strony"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ustawienia Strony"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

After I want to import models to main app calls 'bajki' In app 'bajki' views.py I've create:

```
from ustawienia.models import Ustawienia

def ustawienia(request):
    ustawienia = Ustawienia.objects.all()
    context ={'ustawienia': ustawienia,}
    return render(request, 'bajki/index.html', context=context)
```

And in main app 'bajki' I created a url in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from bajki import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ustawienia, name="ustawienia"),
]
```

In project url I've create something like :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
...
    path('', include('ustawienia.urls')),
]
```

On the end I want to show in `<head>` section the site title configured from admin site:
header.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <html>
      <head>

        <title>{% for ustaw in ustawienia %}{{ustaw.title}}{% endfor %}</title>
```

And the result is : original title dissapear and the new title is not visible. I don't know where is a problem. Why when I set the title in admin form , this title is not visible ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can not simply iterate through items to show in `<title>`. Whenever you iterate for loop in `<title>` HTML will just get confused as to how to represent the data. You can check that code by putting `{% for ustaw in ustawienia %}{{ustaw.title}}{% endfor %}` in `<body>` section.

You can only show one `title` at a time in `<title>`.

Also, change your bajki > views.py a little bit:

```
from ustawienia.models import Ustawienia

def ustawienia(request):
    ustawienia = Ustawienia.objects.order_by('pk')
    context ={'ustawienia': ustawienia,}
    return render(request, 'bajki/index.html', context=context)
```

Reference this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcoi7Dl_LsA

Comment: Dhaval also it's not working in <body> section because I have set the {%for%} in footer. html

Comment: Use `bajki/index.html` this HTML file to insert that for loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all use singleton pattern on your ustawienia model using [django solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo) package. You want to have only one place with main settings. There is only one header and footer on page. Eventually more specific data should be provided with views for example each 'bajka' can have own title.

Let's go back to main settings model. Right now to make your solution working change your views.py to:

```
def ustawienia(request):
    ustawienia = Ustawienia.objects.first()
    context ={'ustawienia': ustawienia}
    return render(request, 'bajki/index.html', context=context)
```

and your template to:

```
<title>{{ ustawienia.title }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ ustawienia.description }}">
```

in place with logo put:

```
{{ ustawienia.logo }}
```

and in place with footer:

```
{{ ustawienia.footer }}
```

The last thing is that your views py should be placed in bajki app. I mean:

1. you should define urls in bajki app
2. you shoud define views in bajki app
3. your views in bajki app should import Ustawienia

Comment: Kamil I have a question. This function ustawienia must be write in ustawienia/views.py or bajki/views.py?

Comment: IMO it will be better in bajki/views.py. And your urls should be placed in bajki/urls.py. Your template is already in bajki/index.html so it is good to have it all consistent.

Comment: So Kamil I made it how You wrote and nothing was happen. Still empty..I created in baji/urls.py the line: path('', views.ustawienia, name="ustawienia"),

Comment: Do you have any Settings object created?

Comment: Yes i have object in Ustawienia